# Integrating factor gives only trivial solution to ODE?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm trying to solve an ODE of the form
\begin{equation}
x\frac{dx}{dt}+\sqrt{x^4-x^2+x+1}=0.
\end{equation}
I'm unable to solve this by just integrating, so I've been trying all sorts of different methods. I don't expect anyone to know how to solve this, (there's a good chance there's no solution consisting of elementary function), just to point out what false assumption or mistake I've made in this attempt!

I look for a function f(x) such that

\begin{equation}
e^tf(x)x\frac{dx}{dt}+e^tf(x)\sqrt{x^4-x^2+x+1}=\frac{d}{dt}e^tf(x)\sqrt{x^4-x^2+x+1}.
\end{equation}
I'll use g(x) for the sake of brevity here. Write out the triple product:
\begin{equation}
e^tf(x)x\frac{dx}{dt}+e^tf(x)g(x)=\frac{d}{dt}e^tf(x)g(x)=e^t\left[f(x)g(x)+\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}g(x)+f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}\right],
\end{equation}
cancel out the $e^t$ and $f(x)g(x)$,
\begin{equation}
f(x)x\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{df}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}g(x)+f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt},
\end{equation}
cancel out $dx/dt$
\begin{equation}
f(x)x=\frac{df}{dx}g(x)+f(x)\frac{dg}{dx},
\end{equation}
rewrite
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{x}{g(x)}-\frac{1}{g(x)}\frac{dg}{dx},
\end{equation}
integrate
\begin{equation}
\text{ln}(f(x))=\text{ln}(\frac{1}{g(x)})+\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx\\
f(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}\text{exp}(\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx).
\end{equation}
So my ODE becomes
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\text{exp}\left[t+\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx\right]=0,
\end{equation}
integrate and take the natural logarithm,
\begin{equation}
\text{exp}\left[t+\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx\right]=c\\
t+\int\frac{x}{g(x)}dx=c,
\end{equation}
I believe I can take a derivative here, as $dx=\frac{dx}{dt}dt$,
\begin{equation}
1+\frac{x}{g(x)}=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^4-x^2+x+1}}=0.
\end{equation}
This is just a quartic equation which could be solved given some google searching and following the procedure to solve it. My problem is that the ODE describes a dynamic system which I know is not described by a static solution, so why do I get such a result? I appreciate if you've taken the time to read this.

Comment: It's separable no need for an integrating factor.

Comment: $\frac{x}{g(x)} dx = -dt$ which gives your implicit relationship between $x$ and $t$ (which you arrived at eventually via your integrating factor approach). Differentiating that with respect to $t$ will again result in a differential equation. Note that differentiating an integral $dx$ with respect to $t$ does not lead to "cancellation" of the derivative and integral.

Comment: But if it's not integrable with one methof it wont be integrable with another method... Here it's obvious that it's separable. The problem is the integral that is hard to evaluate but another method wont change anything. Note that $x=1$ is an obvious solution of the DE.

Comment: @Ian So I am incorrect in treating dx as dx/dt dt? Not canceling out my dx/dt's in the fifth step would have lead to the integral as $\int \frac{x}{g(x)}\frac{dx}{dt}dt$, and thus I'd have (I think) been able to take a derivative to cancel it, under the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Given $\int_{x_0}^x \frac{y}{g(y)} dy = \int_{t_0}^t ds$ (which is what the relationship involving the indefinite integral really means), you could rewrite the left side as $\int_{t_0}^t \frac{x(s)}{g(x(s))} \frac{dx}{dt} ds$ and then differentiate both sides with respect to $t$. But this just results in $\frac{x}{g(x)} \frac{dx}{dt} = 1$ which is trivial. You cannot cancel $\int \dots dx$ with $\frac{d}{dt}$; when you differentiate with respect to a different variable than the variable of integration you need to use the Leibniz rule.

Comment: But $x=-1$ works fine @Ian

Comment: $ x^4-x^2+x+1 =(x+1)(x^3 -x^2+1  ) $

Comment: Good catch, my bad; $x=-1$ is indeed a solution and you won't find that one by separation of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing
$$t'=-\frac x {\sqrt{(x+1)(x^3-x^2+1)}}$$ the real root of the cubic is
$$a=\frac{1}{3} \left(1-2 \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{25}{2}\right)\right)\right)$$ which gives
$$t'=-\frac x {\sqrt{(x+1)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}}$$ where $b$ and $c$ are the two remaining complex conjugate roots of the cubic. For sure, looking at the rhs, we can expect some complicated elliptic integrals.

This would give
$$t+C=-\frac{2 \sqrt{a+1}}{\sqrt{(c+1)(b-a)} }\Big[ \frac {T_1}{\sqrt{a+1}}-T_2\sqrt{-(a+1) }\Big]$$
where
$$T_1=F\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(c+1) (a-x)}{(x+1) (a-c)}}\right)|\frac{(b+1)
   (a-c)}{(c+1) (a-b)}\right)$$
$$T_2=\Pi \left(\frac{c-a}{c+1};\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{(c+1) (a-x)}{(x+1)
   (a-c)}}\right)|\frac{(b+1) (a-c)}{(c+1) (a-b)}\right)$$

I hope and wish no mistakes in the simplifications of the monster produced by a CAS.

*Now, have fun !*